# How to order csv items in a multiCSV exporter scrapy?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I have been putting together a piece of code, I found on stack overflow, on how to split url's output in separate csv files and I came up with the code below. However, I can no longer use field_to_export in the code. I wonder how can I set the field to export so that they are exported like: field_to_export = ['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC'].

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
import re



class appPipeline(object):

    urls = [l.strip() for l in open('data/listOfUrls.txt').readlines()]
    names = [name.group(1) for l in urls for name in [re.search(r'https://www.google.co.uk/', l, re.M|re.I)] if name]


    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}
        self.exporters = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline


    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.files = dict([ (name, open('results/'+name+'.csv','w+b')) for name in self.names])
        self.exporters = dict([ (name,CsvItemExporter(self.files[name])) for name in self.names])
        ### this line is not working self.exportes.fields_to_export = ['itemA','itemB','itemC']
        [e.start_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        [e.finish_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]
        [f.close() for f in self.files.values()]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        myItem = item['myItem']
        if myItem in set(self.names):
            self.exporters[myItem].export_item(item)
        return item
```

So far I have been trying to override the keys in items. I have tried to serialize the items and I have been looking how to sort values in a dictionary by a list of keys. None of them worked.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What exactly needs sorting? myItem in process_item?

Comment: nope items being exported. In scrapy there is a function that when called export the keys in the order you want. It goes in de spider_opened and it is like self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['itemA', 'itemB, 'itemC'].

Comment: If you know how to sort a dict by keys that will solve your problem? I'm still unclear exactly in which line of code sorting needs to happen, perhaps edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @kabanus, I have added the line that is not working. I have tried to sort the self.exportes by keys using this tutorial [link]https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch01s13.html but i did not manage to pass the sorted dict to the rest of the pipeline.